# Semantic Segmentation using dl4j with FCN Networks

Tags: java, bigdata, artificial-intelligence, dl4j

I have checked out dl4j examples and executed **AnimalsClassification** example for testing successfully.

> I have to train, evaluate and predict(use) a semantic segmentation algorithm like **UNet**, because input images are not the same size **FCN** is required.
>
> > and  changed the **network** of **AnimalsClassification** example to **UNet** from this link
> >
> > > https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-zoo/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/zoo/model/UNet.java

but getting error.
Could you please help me to solve this error?

The Error:

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
19:22:39,951 INFO  ~ Load data....
19:22:40,696 INFO  ~ Build model....
19:22:41,363 INFO  ~ Loaded [CpuBackend] backend
19:22:44,955 INFO  ~ Number of threads used for NativeOps: 2
19:22:45,555 INFO  ~ Number of threads used for BLAS: 2
19:22:45,562 INFO  ~ Backend used: [CPU]; OS: [Linux]
19:22:45,562 INFO  ~ Cores: [2]; Memory: [1.3GB];
19:22:45,562 INFO  ~ Blas vendor: [OPENBLAS]
19:22:56,425 WARN  ~ Layer "Layer not named" distribution is set but will not be applied unless weight init is set to WeighInit.DISTRIBUTION.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: network has no inputs. Use .addInputs(String...) to label    (and give an ordering to) the network inputs
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.ComputationGraphConfiguration.validate(ComputationGraphConfiguration.java:279)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.ComputationGraphConfiguration$GraphBuilder.build(ComputationGraphConfiguration.java:918)
    at org.deeplearning4j.examples.convolution.AnimalsClassification.graphBuilder(AnimalsClassification.java:443)
    at org.deeplearning4j.examples.convolution.AnimalsClassification.run(AnimalsClassification.java:145)
    at org.deeplearning4j.examples.convolution.AnimalsClassification.main(AnimalsClassification.java:447)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code I have changed is:

```
package org.deeplearning4j.examples.convolution;

import lombok.Builder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.datavec.api.io.filters.BalancedPathFilter;
import org.datavec.api.io.labels.ParentPathLabelGenerator;
import org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit;
import org.datavec.api.split.InputSplit;
import org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader;
import org.datavec.image.recordreader.ImageRecordReader;
import org.deeplearning4j.api.storage.StatsStorage;
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.MultipleEpochsIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.eval.Evaluation;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.api.OptimizationAlgorithm;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.*;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.distribution.Distribution;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.distribution.GaussianDistribution;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.distribution.NormalDistribution;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.distribution.TruncatedNormalDistribution;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.graph.MergeVertex;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.inputs.InputType;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.*;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.graph.ComputationGraph;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.WeightInit;
import org.deeplearning4j.optimize.listeners.ScoreIterationListener;
import org.deeplearning4j.ui.api.UIServer;
import org.deeplearning4j.ui.stats.StatsListener;
import org.deeplearning4j.ui.storage.InMemoryStatsStorage;
import org.deeplearning4j.util.ModelSerializer;
import org.nd4j.linalg.activations.Activation;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.DataSet;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.iterator.DataSetIterator;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.preprocessor.DataNormalization;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.preprocessor.ImagePreProcessingScaler;
import org.nd4j.linalg.learning.config.AdaDelta;
import org.nd4j.linalg.learning.config.IUpdater;
import org.nd4j.linalg.learning.config.Nesterovs;
import org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions;
import org.nd4j.linalg.schedule.ScheduleType;
import org.nd4j.linalg.schedule.StepSchedule;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import static java.lang.Math.toIntExact;

/**
 * Animal Classification
 *
 * Example classification of photos from 4 different animals (bear, duck, deer, turtle).
 *
 * References:
 *  - U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service (animal sample dataset): http://digitalmedia.fws.gov/cdm/
 *  - Tiny ImageNet Classification with CNN: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2015/pdfs/leonyao_final.pdf
 *
 * CHALLENGE: Current setup gets low score results. Can you improve the scores? Some approaches:
 *  - Add additional images to the dataset
 *  - Apply more transforms to dataset
 *  - Increase epochs
 *  - Try different model configurations
 *  - Tune by adjusting learning rate, updaters, activation & loss functions, regularization, ...
 */

public class AnimalsClassification {
    protected static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnimalsClassification.class);
    protected static int height = 100;
    protected static int width = 100;
    protected static int channels = 3;
    protected static int batchSize = 20;

//    protected static long seed = 42;
    private static long seed = 1234;
    protected static Random rng = new Random(seed);
    protected static int epochs = 50;
    protected static double splitTrainTest = 0.8;
    protected static boolean save = false;

    protected static String modelType = "AlexNet"; // LeNet, AlexNet or Custom but you need to fill it out
    private int numLabels;

    public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        log.info("Load data....");
        /**cd
         * Data Setup -> organize and limit data file paths:
         *  - mainPath = path to image files
         *  - fileSplit = define basic dataset split with limits on format
         *  - pathFilter = define additional file load filter to limit size and balance batch content
         **/
        ParentPathLabelGenerator labelMaker = new ParentPathLabelGenerator();
        File mainPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "dl4j-examples/src/main/resources/animals/");
        FileSplit fileSplit = new FileSplit(mainPath, NativeImageLoader.ALLOWED_FORMATS, rng);
        int numExamples = toIntExact(fileSplit.length());
        numLabels = fileSplit.getRootDir().listFiles(File::isDirectory).length; //This only works if your root is clean: only label subdirs.
        BalancedPathFilter pathFilter = new BalancedPathFilter(rng, labelMaker, numExamples, numLabels, batchSize);

        /**
         * Data Setup -> train test split
         *  - inputSplit = define train and test split
         **/
        InputSplit[] inputSplit = fileSplit.sample(pathFilter, splitTrainTest, 1 - splitTrainTest);
        InputSplit trainData = inputSplit[0];
        InputSplit testData = inputSplit[1];

        /**
         * Data Setup -> transformation
         *  - Transform = how to tranform images and generate large dataset to train on
         **/
//        ImageTransform flipTransform1 = new FlipImageTransform(rng);
//        ImageTransform flipTransform2 = new FlipImageTransform(new Random(123));
//        ImageTransform warpTransform = new WarpImageTransform(rng, 42);
//        ImageTransform colorTransform = new ColorConversionTransform(new Random(seed), COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);
//        List<ImageTransform> transforms = Arrays.asList(new ImageTransform[]{flipTransform1, warpTransform, flipTransform2});

        /**
         * Data Setup -> normalization
         *  - how to normalize images and generate large dataset to train on
         **/
        DataNormalization scaler = new ImagePreProcessingScaler(0, 1);

        log.info("Build model....");

        // Uncomment below to try AlexNet. Note change height and width to at least 100
//        MultiLayerNetwork network = new AlexNet(height, width, channels, numLabels, seed, iterations).init();

//        MultiLayerNetwork network;
//        switch (modelType) {
//            case "LeNet":
//                network = lenetModel();
//                break;
//            case "AlexNet":
//                network = alexnetModel();
//                break;
//            case "custom":
//                network = customModel();
//                break;
//            default:
//                throw new InvalidInputTypeException("Incorrect model provided.");
//        }
        ComputationGraph network = new ComputationGraph(graphBuilder());
        network.init();
       // network.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(listenerFreq));
        UIServer uiServer = UIServer.getInstance();
        StatsStorage statsStorage = new InMemoryStatsStorage();
        uiServer.attach(statsStorage);
        network.setListeners(new StatsListener( statsStorage),new ScoreIterationListener(1));
        /**
         * Data Setup -> define how to load data into net:
         *  - recordReader = the reader that loads and converts image data pass in inputSplit to initialize
         *  - dataIter = a generator that only loads one batch at a time into memory to save memory
         *  - trainIter = uses MultipleEpochsIterator to ensure model runs through the data for all epochs
         **/
        ImageRecordReader recordReader = new ImageRecordReader(height, width, channels, labelMaker);
        DataSetIterator dataIter;
        MultipleEpochsIterator trainIter;


        log.info("Train model....");
        // Train without transformations
        recordReader.initialize(trainData, null);
        dataIter = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, batchSize, 1, numLabels);
        scaler.fit(dataIter);
        dataIter.setPreProcessor(scaler);
        trainIter = new MultipleEpochsIterator(epochs, dataIter);
        network.fit(trainIter);

        // Train with transformations
/*        for (ImageTransform transform : transforms) {
            System.out.print("\nTraining on transformation: " + transform.getClass().toString() + "\n\n");
            recordReader.initialize(trainData, transform);
            dataIter = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, batchSize, 1, numLabels);
            scaler.fit(dataIter);
            dataIter.setPreProcessor(scaler);
            trainIter = new MultipleEpochsIterator(epochs, dataIter);
            network.fit(trainIter);
        }*/

        log.info("Evaluate model....");
        recordReader.initialize(testData);
        dataIter = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, batchSize, 1, numLabels);
        scaler.fit(dataIter);
        dataIter.setPreProcessor(scaler);
        Evaluation eval = network.evaluate(dataIter);
        log.info(eval.stats(true));

        // Example on how to get predict results with trained model. Result for first example in minibatch is printed
        dataIter.reset();
        DataSet testDataSet = dataIter.next();
        List<String> allClassLabels = recordReader.getLabels();
        int labelIndex = testDataSet.getLabels().argMax(1).getInt(0);
//        int[] predictedClasses = network.predict(testDataSet.getFeatures());
        String expectedResult = allClassLabels.get(labelIndex);
//        String modelPrediction = allClassLabels.get(predictedClasses[0]);
//        System.out.print("\nFor a single example that is labeled " + expectedResult + " the model predicted " + modelPrediction + "\n\n");

        if (save) {
            log.info("Save model....");
            String basePath = FilenameUtils.concat(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src/main/resources/");
            ModelSerializer.writeModel(network, basePath + "model.bin", true);
        }
        log.info("****************Example finished********************");
    }

    private ConvolutionLayer convInit(String name, int in, int out, int[] kernel, int[] stride, int[] pad, double bias) {
        return new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(kernel, stride, pad).name(name).nIn(in).nOut(out).biasInit(bias).build();
    }

    private ConvolutionLayer conv3x3(String name, int out, double bias) {
        return new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(new int[]{3,3}, new int[] {1,1}, new int[] {1,1}).name(name).nOut(out).biasInit(bias).build();
    }

    private ConvolutionLayer conv5x5(String name, int out, int[] stride, int[] pad, double bias) {
        return new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(new int[]{5,5}, stride, pad).name(name).nOut(out).biasInit(bias).build();
    }

    private SubsamplingLayer maxPool(String name,  int[] kernel) {
        return new SubsamplingLayer.Builder(kernel, new int[]{2,2}).name(name).build();
    }

    private DenseLayer fullyConnected(String name, int out, double bias, double dropOut, Distribution dist) {
        return new DenseLayer.Builder().name(name).nOut(out).biasInit(bias).dropOut(dropOut).dist(dist).build();
    }

    public MultiLayerNetwork lenetModel() {
        /**
         * Revisde Lenet Model approach developed by ramgo2 achieves slightly above random
         * Reference: https://gist.github.com/ramgo2/833f12e92359a2da9e5c2fb6333351c5
         **/
        MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(seed)
            .l2(0.005)
            .activation(Activation.RELU)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .updater(new Nesterovs(0.0001,0.9))
            .list()
            .layer(0, convInit("cnn1", channels, 50 ,  new int[]{5, 5}, new int[]{1, 1}, new int[]{0, 0}, 0))
            .layer(1, maxPool("maxpool1", new int[]{2,2}))
            .layer(2, conv5x5("cnn2", 100, new int[]{5, 5}, new int[]{1, 1}, 0))
            .layer(3, maxPool("maxool2", new int[]{2,2}))
            .layer(4, new DenseLayer.Builder().nOut(500).build())
            .layer(5, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                .nOut(numLabels)
                .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                .build())
            .backprop(true).pretrain(false)
            .setInputType(InputType.convolutional(height, width, channels))
            .build();

        return new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);

    }

    public MultiLayerNetwork alexnetModel() {
        /**
         * AlexNet model interpretation based on the original paper ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks
         * and the imagenetExample code referenced.
         * http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf
         **/

        double nonZeroBias = 1;
        double dropOut = 0.5;

        MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(seed)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.DISTRIBUTION)
            .dist(new NormalDistribution(0.0, 0.01))
            .activation(Activation.RELU)
            .updater(new Nesterovs(new StepSchedule(ScheduleType.ITERATION, 1e-2, 0.1, 100000), 0.9))
            .biasUpdater(new Nesterovs(new StepSchedule(ScheduleType.ITERATION, 2e-2, 0.1, 100000), 0.9))
            .gradientNormalization(GradientNormalization.RenormalizeL2PerLayer) // normalize to prevent vanishing or exploding gradients
            .l2(5 * 1e-4)
            .list()
            .layer(0, convInit("cnn1", channels, 96, new int[]{11, 11}, new int[]{4, 4}, new int[]{3, 3}, 0))
            .layer(1, new LocalResponseNormalization.Builder().name("lrn1").build())
            .layer(2, maxPool("maxpool1", new int[]{3,3}))
            .layer(3, conv5x5("cnn2", 256, new int[] {1,1}, new int[] {2,2}, nonZeroBias))
            .layer(4, new LocalResponseNormalization.Builder().name("lrn2").build())
            .layer(5, maxPool("maxpool2", new int[]{3,3}))
            .layer(6,conv3x3("cnn3", 384, 0))
            .layer(7,conv3x3("cnn4", 384, nonZeroBias))
            .layer(8,conv3x3("cnn5", 256, nonZeroBias))
            .layer(9, maxPool("maxpool3", new int[]{3,3}))
            .layer(10, fullyConnected("ffn1", 4096, nonZeroBias, dropOut, new GaussianDistribution(0, 0.005)))
            .layer(11, fullyConnected("ffn2", 4096, nonZeroBias, dropOut, new GaussianDistribution(0, 0.005)))
            .layer(12, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                .name("output")
                .nOut(numLabels)
                .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                .build())
            .backprop(true)
            .pretrain(false)
            .setInputType(InputType.convolutional(height, width, channels))
            .build();

        return new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);

    }

    public static MultiLayerNetwork customModel() {
        /**
         * Use this method to build your own custom model.
         **/
        return null;
    }

    @Builder.Default private int[] inputShape = new int[] {3, 512, 512};
    @Builder.Default private int numClasses = 0;
    @Builder.Default private WeightInit weightInit = WeightInit.RELU;
    @Builder.Default private IUpdater updater = new AdaDelta();
    @Builder.Default private CacheMode cacheMode = CacheMode.NONE;
//    @Builder.Default private WorkspaceMode workspaceMode = WorkspaceMode.ENABLED;
    @Builder.Default private WorkspaceMode workspaceMode = WorkspaceMode.SINGLE;
    @Builder.Default private ConvolutionLayer.AlgoMode cudnnAlgoMode = ConvolutionLayer.AlgoMode.PREFER_FASTEST;

    public ComputationGraphConfiguration graphBuilder() {

        ComputationGraphConfiguration.GraphBuilder graph = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder().seed(seed)
            .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT)
            .updater(updater)
            .weightInit(weightInit)
            .dist(new TruncatedNormalDistribution(0.0, 0.5))
            .l2(5e-5)
            .miniBatch(true)
            .cacheMode(cacheMode)
            .trainingWorkspaceMode(workspaceMode)
            .inferenceWorkspaceMode(workspaceMode)
            .graphBuilder();


        graph
            .addLayer("conv1-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(64)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "input")
            .addLayer("conv1-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(64)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv1-1")
            .addLayer("pool1", new SubsamplingLayer.Builder(SubsamplingLayer.PoolingType.MAX).kernelSize(2,2)
                .build(), "conv1-2")

            .addLayer("conv2-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(128)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "pool1")
            .addLayer("conv2-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(128)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv2-1")
            .addLayer("pool2", new SubsamplingLayer.Builder(SubsamplingLayer.PoolingType.MAX).kernelSize(2,2)
                .build(), "conv2-2")

            .addLayer("conv3-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(256)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "pool2")
            .addLayer("conv3-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(256)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv3-1")
            .addLayer("pool3", new SubsamplingLayer.Builder(SubsamplingLayer.PoolingType.MAX).kernelSize(2,2)
                .build(), "conv3-2")

            .addLayer("conv4-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(512)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "pool3")
            .addLayer("conv4-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(512)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv4-1")
            .addLayer("drop4", new DropoutLayer.Builder(0.5).build(), "conv4-2")
            .addLayer("pool4", new SubsamplingLayer.Builder(SubsamplingLayer.PoolingType.MAX).kernelSize(2,2)
                .build(), "drop4")

            .addLayer("conv5-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(1024)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "pool4")
            .addLayer("conv5-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(1024)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv5-1")
            .addLayer("drop5", new DropoutLayer.Builder(0.5).build(), "conv5-2")

            // up6
            .addLayer("up6-1", new Upsampling2D.Builder(2).build(), "drop5")
            .addLayer("up6-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(2,2).stride(1,1).nOut(512)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "up6-1")
            .addVertex("merge6", new MergeVertex(), "drop4", "up6-2")
            .addLayer("conv6-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(512)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "merge6")
            .addLayer("conv6-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(512)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv6-1")

            // up7
            .addLayer("up7-1", new Upsampling2D.Builder(2).build(), "conv6-2")
            .addLayer("up7-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(2,2).stride(1,1).nOut(256)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "up7-1")
            .addVertex("merge7", new MergeVertex(), "conv3-2", "up7-2")
            .addLayer("conv7-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(256)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "merge7")
            .addLayer("conv7-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(256)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv7-1")

            // up8
            .addLayer("up8-1", new Upsampling2D.Builder(2).build(), "conv7-2")
            .addLayer("up8-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(2,2).stride(1,1).nOut(128)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "up8-1")
            .addVertex("merge8", new MergeVertex(), "conv2-2", "up8-2")
            .addLayer("conv8-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(128)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "merge8")
            .addLayer("conv8-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(128)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv8-1")

            // up9
            .addLayer("up9-1", new Upsampling2D.Builder(2).build(), "conv8-2")
            .addLayer("up9-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(2,2).stride(1,1).nOut(64)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "up8-1")
            .addVertex("merge9", new MergeVertex(), "conv1-2", "up9-2")
            .addLayer("conv9-1", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(64)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "merge9")
            .addLayer("conv9-2", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(64)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv9-1")
            .addLayer("conv9-3", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(2)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.RELU).build(), "conv9-2")

            .addLayer("conv10", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(3,3).stride(1,1).nOut(1)
                .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Truncate).cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                .activation(Activation.SIGMOID).build(), "conv9-3")
            .addLayer("output", new CnnLossLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MCXENT).build(), "conv10")

            .setOutputs("output").backprop(true).pretrain(false);

        return graph.build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new AnimalsClassification().run(args);
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says what the error is right in the stack trace. You need to  call setInputs on the graph. It's similar to how we set the outputs at the bottom.
Please read the error message closer.

Comment: Thank you very much. could you please introduce a good book or tutorial for dl4j? 
Its tutorial is not clear for me. (nothing about UNet.)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect us to have a tutorial on every conceivable neural net architecture. No one has that. This is just a general concept you should understand. Look at the computation graph page: http://deeplearning4j.org/computationgraph , and look at our examples. https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples using github code search. After that, ask around on our gitter: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j